# How do I keep track of a person's total leaderstats in different games?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

For example, I would have a main lobby in my Roblox game. Then, a player gets sent into another game and collects coins. When they come back to the lobby after they get a certain amount of coins, I want it to save their all time coins.

I would share code, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Comment: you can add code directly your question, by using a [markdown code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), this is for small sections of code that you want to show a specific problem in. You can also add a link to a pastebin or github for large files or whole projects, this should be avoid. It is best if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Nifim Okay! I'll try to script my own thing first and put it in there. And I meant I didn't know how to code it, i know how to put code in though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roblox "Games" can hold multiple "Places". Up to 20, I believe, including the "Starting Place". The neat thing about this is that datastores are saved across the entire *game*. As a result, if you save someone's data in place1, then they move to place2, their data will carry over.
To learn more about Games vs. Places, you can visit the [developer API documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/games-and-places).

EDIT: Alternatively, if you want data to save across multiple *games*, you would have to look into HTTPService, and off-roblox datastores.